# Create TRUE/FALSE column in a list of dataframes based on values of specific rows

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, logical-operators

I have a list of dataframes containing values from different 'null' and 'alternative' statistical models. I would like to create a new column within each dataframe which contains a TRUE or FALSE value for each row. All 'null' models should be assigned as FALSE. All 'alternative' models should be FALSE where its value is less than double that of the null model with the highest value. But any alternative models at least twice that of the highest null model value should be TRUE.

So for example, if I have two alternative models with values of 3 and 4, and two null models with values of 1 and 2, then I would want FALSE values for one alternative model (value = 3) and the 2 null models. But one alternative model (value =4) should be TRUE because it is twice the highest null model value (value = 2). I have reproduced this in the 'Test' example below.

I can achieve this for a single data frame ('Test' example), but I do not know how to loop this through a list of dataframes. Some reproducible code:

```
####Data import
M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 4, ncol = 1))
M2 <- data.frame(matrix(8:11, nrow = 4, ncol = 1))
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(0:3, nrow = 4, ncol = 1))
mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3)
mlist <- lapply(mlist, transform, Logical= NA)##CREATE NEW COLUMN FOR EACH DF

###Define models
row_names <- c("NULL1","NULL2","ALT1","ALT2") 
mlist <- lapply(mlist, "rownames<-", row_names)
```

I am not sure what to do from here though. Here is the procedure that I would adopt for a single dataframe.

```
###Perform for one DF individually
Test <- mlist[[1]]
null_models<-which(rownames(Test)=="NULL1" | rownames(Test)== "NULL2")

for (i in 1:nrow(Test)){
  if (all(Test[null_models,1]<=(Test[i,1]/2))) {
   Test$Logical[i]<-"TRUE"
} else {
Test$Logical[i]<-"FALSE"
}}
Test
```

But I do not know how to apply this code across a list of dataframes. Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Comment: `Test$Logical[i] <- all(Test[null_models,1]<=(Test[i,1]/2))`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But my issue is applying this technique simultaneously across a list of data frames. I.e. how to perform this within mlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Wrap your code in a function which takes one argument (the list element).

```
customFunction <- function(x) {
  Test <- x
  null_models <- which(rownames(Test) == "NULL1" | rownames(Test) == "NULL2")

  for (i in 1:nrow(Test)){
    if (all(Test[null_models, 1]<=(Test[i,1]/2))) {
      Test$Logical[i]<-"TRUE"
    } else {
      Test$Logical[i]<-"FALSE"
    }}
  Test
}

> lapply(mlist, FUN = customFunction)
[[1]]
      matrix.1.4..nrow...4..ncol...1. Logical
NULL1                               1   FALSE
NULL2                               2   FALSE
ALT1                                3   FALSE
ALT2                                4    TRUE

[[2]]
      matrix.8.11..nrow...4..ncol...1. Logical
NULL1                                8   FALSE
NULL2                                9   FALSE
ALT1                                10   FALSE
ALT2                                11   FALSE

[[3]]
      matrix.0.3..nrow...4..ncol...1. Logical
NULL1                               0   FALSE
NULL2                               1   FALSE
ALT1                                2    TRUE
ALT2                                3    TRUE
```

Here is a short variant of the inner loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Test)) Test$Logical[i] <- all(Test[null_models,1]<=(Test[i,1]/2))
```

Also substitution of the loop by a `apply()`-call is possible (i.e. loop hiding):

```
T0 <- Test[null_models,1]
Test$Logical <- apply(T0 <= matrix(Test[,1]/2, length(null_models), nrow(Test), byrow = TRUE), 2, all)
```

or

```
Test$Logical <- apply(sapply(Test[null_models,1], '<=', Test[,1]/2), 1, all)
```

Comment: @jogo feel free to append this information to my answer.